# Getting ClassCastException when trying to cast Logger object to my own wrapper logger

Tags: rest, spring-boot, microservices, log4j2

I am trying write a wrapper logger class by extending Logger, which will log class name , method name, message and error/exception details.

Getting exception in below line

```
ILogger logger = 
(CustomLogger)org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(name);
```

Using below XML, sometimes it's taking SLF4J logger too and getting SLF4j binding exceptions too.

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.Logger</groupId>
<artifactId>WrapperLogger</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>WrapperLogger</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

===================================================================

log4j.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
<Appenders>
<!-- Console Appender -->
<Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
  <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss a} [%t] %M,%C, 
  %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
</Console>
<!-- File Appender -->
<File name="File" fileName="d:/app.log">
  <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss a} [%t] %-5level 
  %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
</File>
</Appenders>

<Loggers>
<!-- Log everything in custom package -->
<Logger name="com.boraji.tutorial.springboot" level="debug" additivity="false">
  <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
  <AppenderRef ref="File" />
</Logger>
<!-- Log everything in Spring Boot -->
<Logger name="org.springframework.boot" level="debug" additivity="false">
  <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
  <AppenderRef ref="File" />
</Logger>

<!-- Log everything in Spring Core -->
<Logger name="org.springframework.core" level="debug" additivity="false">
  <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
  <AppenderRef ref="File" />
</Logger>

<Root level="info">
  <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
  <AppenderRef ref="File" />
</Root>
```

Comment: You will probably need to show us the definition of CustomLogger...

Comment: i referred to this blog for custom logger (http://sureshgarrepalli.blogspot.com/2016/03/building-logging-wrapper-on-top-of.html)

Answer (score 0):

To remove `slf4j binding exceptions`, you should probably remove `spring-boot-starter-logging` dependency from your `pom.xml`.

Actually, this dependency is already added by `spring-boot-starter` artificat so you need to exclude it like below -

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
       <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
```

Comment: Hi Vikas thank you, it's working in my local system wheni am trying to implement in my office project it's not working. Though i tried with exclusion  of SLF4J and default logging .

Comment: Can you share details of both project and how you have implemented custom logger.

Comment: i referred to this blog for custom logger (http://sureshgarrepalli.blogspot.com/2016/03/building-logging-wrapper-on-top-of.html)